# Making clickable text in Python

Tags: python, hyperlink

i wonder if it's possible to print text that triggers an if statement when clicked on (like some type of an input)

I want to use this for displaying options. In my example there should be an output line like:

"Select a molecule to calcute its energy values: **H2** **HBr** **HCl** **Cl2** **LiH**"

And when you click on one of the bold printed structures the appropriate if statement should be triggered.

Thanks for help!

Comment: In what context? Console? Tkinter? A website? Jupyter?

Comment: In the console would bei nice